# How can I add a paper to ResearchGate when it does not recognize the title and ISBN of the journal it is published in?

Tags: publications, repository

I was trying to post a paper on ResearchGate published in a recognized journal. ResearchGate did not accept the journal title or ISBN. I could not contact anyone at ResearchGate for help.

The message on the ResearchGate site claims that they are working on it - the message is several months old.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you actually have the rights to do that? Who holds copyright? You? The journal? If you don't hold the rights, then my suggestion is to stop.

Comment: I wonder if Research Gate has changed in the last few years regarding "publications". I archived an unpublished manuscript there a few years ago and don't recall having to jump through any hoops (unlike arXiv, where I originally wanted to put it). In fact, as described in [this comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166833/is-it-absolutely-necessary-for-a-researcher-to-have-an-institutional-email#comment448846_166833), I didn't even initiate trying to get an account with them, but instead finally decided after several months of "spam emails" from them.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro there aren't any hoops you have to jump trough, all research can still be added easily to RG, the only issue is that when you upload a paper, you cannot enter a journal, but have to choose from a list. If your journal isn't on the list, you can simply skip this and post your research anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Not every journal is in the list of journals to chose from when adding a publication to RG. This is not a new issue and if you search the questions on RG, you will find several addressing just this issue, e.g. [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Journal_Not_Listed). Only reputable enough journals (whatever that means for RG) are added to the list.

So no, RG is not "dead" (I frequently use it), it just seems that the journal you published your article in might not be in their list. You can still add your article, just omit the journal info.